# On the merit of text-to-speech system during manuscript writing

Tags: research-process, paper-submission, writing, procrastination

**Background** - I am an educative staff in an university. In my country, there is **not** a tenure system, but I can work here until the specified retired age. I am suffering from every kind of procrastination.

**Situation** - My lab students routinely write theses every year but in a local language other than English. I always feel extensive rewrite in addition to the language translation is necessary to submit it as a journal paper, which tempts me to the above-mentioned procrastination.

Let me ask a question to an academician who knows life-hacks well. I am thinking that a writing is a psychological battle with myself. Someone recommends me a text-to-speech (TTS) system. Can you also recommend a TTS software? Please tell me how to easily build such a TTS environment. Do you think such an environment encourages me to finalize those drafts?

Answer (score 1):

Apple devices have it built in, which I always used to use, but I have switched to using Speechify, which is more suited to this type of work.

It's helpful both in reading articles that you want to really understand deeply, and helps with editing. It is helpful to hear your work in another voice in order to be both self critical and ensure the writing flows well. But, at least in English, something that is perfectly grammatically correct in written form could sound odd when heard out-loud, so it's a good idea to not rely too heavily on TTS.

Comment: Can Speechify read Math equations ?

Comment: I appreciate your post. thanks.

Comment: @Nobody I just checked and yes it does manage those alright.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow the logic of your question. It seems like you need machine translation more than text to speech. Assuming your dissertation students are a good source of material for publications you want your name on. I don't expect to publish very many of my own students' dissertations; I encourage the best to publish themselves, and try to get the ones who aspire to write publishable work to write not only in English but in Latex. Then you can focus on your own work, and just edit their articles if and when they get to that phase.

On the other hand, I have used speech to text to write sometimes, particularly when I had a typing injury. That can help.